# How to create iflix home page layout

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

Hi guys, please give me an idea how to create a list similar to the homepage of [iflix](https://iflix.com) (image attached below). I tried using table view with collection view inside the cell, but I don't like the performance because it flickers when I scroll because of the reloading of collection view cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell

        cell.bind(data: self.datas[indexPath.row])

        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        cell.delegate = self


        return cell
    }
```

When I removed the `cell.collectionView.reloadData()` the scrolling is smooth but the displaying of data is incorrect because cells are reusing.

Can anyone give me a better idea on how to implement a layout like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how the data is incorrect ? only images are incorrect or names of movies as well ?

Comment: names and images, but when I call cell.collectionView.reloadData() the data will be correct. But it cause lagging on the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

there could be a variety of reasons why you are experiencing flickering, in fact the first release of that ViewController had the same issue on older devices.  I would recommend first Analysing your app using the Time profiler to investigate the cause of the flickering you are experiencing.  It’s very likely, as we discovered there there is not one main cause but a collection of smaller issues that when added together on the main thread causes the flickering.  Below I will detail a brief description of how we manage to reduce the flickering effect.

The ViewController contains one vertical collection view, each row is its own cell that owns a horizontal collection view.

One thing we try to ensure is that drawing a cell is as efficient as possible. All cells and views are configured via ViewModels which for our case is a PODO (property only data object).
The ViewModels can be easily preprocessed on a background thread and contain e.g url, titles, hide/show buttons, cell sizes etc for any orientation.  Plus it makes it very easy to test.  We ensure that all images are the correct size so there is no time required to scale the image, along with that each visual item is opaque and rasterised to the correct screen scale.  We also found for our code that if each cell uses ‘preferredLayoutAttributesFitting’ that can help to reduce the flicker also.

The next part is to try to help reduce the amount of effort taken to when calling reloadData.  If each cell in the row is the same size then using UICollectionViewDataSource can be more process intensive than setting the item size, instead you can set the itemSize in the xib/storybaord or use a UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  Before a cell is shown to the user the methods “collectionView cellForItemAt” and “collectionView willDisplay” will be called, you can try and split cell configuration work over those two method calls.

I hope that helps.